# Batch file to open cmd.exe then run consecutive commands at prompt

Tags: batch, cmd.exe

I want to open cmd.exe, `cd` into a specific directory, activate a Python virtual environment, then move up two directories.

I would have expected this to work:

```
start cmd.exe /K cd /d D:\_LOCAL TORAGE\PROGRAMMING\python\_projects\ZOOMg2MIDI\z2MIDI_venv\scripts\
activate
cd ..
cd ..
```

but it only gives me the command prompt at the desired directory, i.e. only the first line is executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `&` to separate commands, not by enter, and the last two lines you can write as `cd ..\..`.

So the command would be:

```
start cmd.exe /K cd /d D:\_LOCAL TORAGE\PROGRAMMING\python\_projects\ZOOMg2MIDI\z2MIDI_venv\scripts\ & activate & cd ..\..
```

You may need to put the commands into quotes `"` to make them work with one `start` command:

```
start cmd.exe /K "cd /d D:\_LOCAL TORAGE\PROGRAMMING\python\_projects\ZOOMg2MIDI\z2MIDI_venv\scripts\ & activate & cd ..\.."
```

Comment: Thanks, putting it in quotes worked for me. (Just using '&' didn't for some reason.)

Comment: @dsb27 & should be inside quotes.

Comment: Also, if you call .bat files you need to prepend them with word `call` - so they would not replace the current bat file running.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you want to see the output of all the commands in the new window, you can use:

```
start cmd.exe /K python.bat
```

Then create `python.bat` similar to this:

```
call cd /d "D:\_LOCAL TORAGE\PROGRAMMING\python\_projects\ZOOMg2MIDI\z2MIDI_venv\scripts\
call activate
call cd ..\..
```